# Kotlin delegate disrupting Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying `Jetpack Navigation component` and have set up a very basic navigation graph with just 2 Fragments with one home fragment (`Foo`) containing a button which calls a navigation action to open the other fragment (`Bar`).

With only the basic Android usage and functions it works as intended, I can navigate back to `Foo` by pressing the back button and navigate forward to `Bar` again.

I implemented this convenience `delegate` class for binding views by id in my preferred way (Im originally an iOS dev).

```kotlin
class FindViewById<in R, T: View>(private val id: Int) {

    private var view: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        var view = this.view
        if (view == null) {
            view = when (thisRef) {
                is Activity -> thisRef.findViewById(id)!!
                is Fragment -> thisRef.requireView().findViewById(id)!!
                is View -> thisRef.findViewById(id)!!
                else -> throw NullPointerException()
            }
            this.view = view // Comment out to never cache reference
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

This allows me to write code like this

```kotlin
class FragmentFoo: Fragment() {
    
    private val textView: TextView by FindViewById(R.id.text_view)
    private val button: Button by FindViewById(R.id.button)
    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        button.setOnClickListener { 
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_foo_to_bar)
        }
    }
}
```

Now all of a sudden when I navigate to `Bar` and then press the back button I arrive at `Foo` again but I cannot navigate forward to `Bar`. If I remove the line `this.view = view` in `FindViewById` it works again.

My guess is there is some memory related issue, though I tried wrapping the `view` inside a `WeakReference` but it didn't solve the problem.

I think it is a good idea performance-wise to cache the found view in the delegate.

Any idea why this is occurring and how I can resolve the problem while caching the found view?

#### Edit

My intention is not to find another way of referencing views but rather why this delegate implementation disrupts the Navigation component so I don't experience it again if I were to make another custom delegate in the future.

## Solution

```kotlin
is Fragment -> {
    thisRef.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.value!!.lifecycle.addObserver(object: LifecycleEventObserver {
        override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) this@FindViewById.view = null
        }
    })
    return thisRef.requireView().findViewById(id)!!
}
```

Comment: you don't need this delegate at all... the system does it for you, just invoke the view as its id name

instead of findViewById(R.id.blabla)
use it as blabla.doSomething()

Comment: @LenaBru I know about kotlin synthetic, but I dont like it for the same reason I dont like ViewBinding. It's just a preference thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In android `Fragment` view has its own well-defined [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) and this lifecycle is managed independently from that of the fragment's Lifecycle.

When you are using navigation component it uses a [fragment replace transaction](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions) under the hood and adds the previous fragment to the back stack. At this point this fragment goes into `CREATED` state and as you can see on this [diagram](https://developer.android.com/images/guide/fragments/fragment-view-lifecycle.png) its view is actually destroyed. At this point your delegate still keeps the reference to this old view hierarchy, causing a memory leak.

Later, when you are navigating back, the fragment goes back through `STARTED` into `RESUMED` state, but **the view hierarchy is recreated** - `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` methods are called again during this process. So while the fragment displays a completely new view hierarchy, your delegate still references the old one.

So if you'd like to manually cache any view references, you need to override `onDestroyView` and clear these references to avoid memory leaks and this kind of incorrect behavior. Also for this particular problem I'd recommend using [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

If you'd like to have your own implementation, but do not like to clear references in `onDestroyView` (e.g. because it breaks nice and self-contained abstraction), [viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData()) might be useful to observe current view state and clear all references when view is destroyed.

Please check out the [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) documentation, it has been recently updated and covers most aspects of fragments.

Comment: I see, though I tried using WeakReference class. But since java uses a garbage collector rather than a reference counter perhaps the view never got erased even when its parent got removed?

Comment: Yes, GC in java does not have to perform collection immediately and in a simple app which does not create a lot of objects, it can take a while for GC to collect it. If you'd like to check it, android studio includes a pretty good [memory profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) where you can check the references.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the lifeCycle method to erase the reference onStop and it works.